# Выделить цветом первую букву каждого слова в предложении

Tags: css, вёрстка

Это можно сделать только посредством css не оборачивая слова в html?

Поиск по google дал `::first-letter` и `text-transform`, но это не то.

Answer (score 2):

Сделать это средствами css невозможно. Более того, выделение предложения - непростая семантическая задача. Точки не годятся (г. Москва, 1990 г.р., гр. Иванов и т.д. и т.п.)

Разумные результаты по выделению предложений мне удалось получить лишь с помощью Томита-парсера от Яндекс. Но он работает на php.

Comment: В исходном вопросе я немного не это имел в виду. Предложение фиксированно (некоторый текст, обернутый в `div`), и в этом конкретном `div`е надо первую букву каждого слова выделить цветом.
И чтобы новый мелкий вопрос не открывать, не могли бы ответить на следующий:
"Как сделать отступ между абзацами с помощью псевдоэлементов?"

Comment: Ну, если предложение искать не надо, то задача намного легче, но опять же, решается только через js.

Comment: А зачем именно с помощью псевдоэлементоа? Чем обычный padding-bottom/margin-bottom не угодил? Но если сильно хочется, добавьте тот же margin блоку after

Answer (score 0):

Почему то в сниппете не работает но вот песочница [codepen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qJpeyd) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCvsu/1/)

```css
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words = $('.word').text().split(' ');
    var html = '';
    $.each(words, function() {
        html += '<span style="font-size:120%;color:red;text-transform:uppercase;">'+this.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+this.substring(1) + ' ';
    });
    $('.word').html(html);
});
```

```html
<p class="word">
  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. os enim nemo, aperiam sunt alias corrupti harum inventore architecto repudiandae!
</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Js можно решить, кто ж спорит.

Comment: Ну и вы первую букву каждого слова ввделяете, а не предложения..

Comment: @KAGGDesign на css только оборачивать в span а так такого css свойства не существует

Comment: @KAGGDesign в заголовке сказано что надо выделить первую букву в каждом слове

Comment: А, точно. Так и есть.

Comment: Я-то знаю, что не существует, и написал в своём ответе - невозможно. Но ТС просил именно на css

Comment: @KAGGDesign  но к примеру увеличить каждый первый знак можно но закрасить другим цветом нет